# I lost the CD to reformat my ASUS Notebook PC, can I use the set from another machine?

Tags: asus-laptop, cd

I have an ASUS Notebook PC, i5, 14 inches, X45OL and I need to reformat it. Unfortunately I can't find the CDs that goes along with the laptop that can be used to reformat my laptop.

So, I have a friend that has same laptop, same model etc. Can I borrow or use his CDs to reformat my laptop?

Comment: ok thank you for responding. sorry if i bothered u with my uppercase letters haha

Answer (score -1):

Well you could always use the media creation tools if you have windows 8 or 10 and then just do a fresh install. There is a tutorial on how to geek (http://www.howtogeek.com/186775/how-to-download-windows-7-8-and-8.1-installation-media-legally/)

Windows 10 Media creation tool - https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10

Windows 8 Media creation tool - https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows8

Windows 7 but you will need you product key - https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows7